# Can't read file with chmod 777

Tags: permissions, chmod

**Shell**

```
[root@server~]# su -s /bin/bash user123
bash-4.1$ cat /home/user567/folder/textfile.txt
cat: /home/user567/folder/textfile.txt: Permission denied
```

**File permissions**

/home/user567/folder/textfile.txt:

```
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (  567/user567)   Gid: (  567/user567)

[root@server~]# ls -l /home/user567/folder/textfile.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user567 user567 826 Jan 19 17:30 /home/user567/folder/textfile.txt
```

/home/user567/folder:

```
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (  567/user567)   Gid: (  567/user567)
```

/home/user567:

```
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (  567/user567)   Gid: (  567/user567)
```

**Information**

OS: `CentOS 6`

SELinux: `Disabled`

lsattr on file `-------------e- /home/user567/folder/textfile.txt`

Comment: You write that `/home/user567` has permissions 0755, but show them as `rwxrwxrwx` even though 0755 ought to mean `rwxr-xr-x`.  Are the other permissions as you actually say?

Comment: use `lsattr` to check if the file was made immutable.

Comment: Edited the question based on your comments

Comment: I've added the information you requested

Comment: What says `getfacl /home/user567/folder/textfile.txt` ?

Comment: @marco208:  Would you care to provide the output of `ls -lad /home/user567`?

Comment: Can you do a demo, on your computer, then paste the whole session, as one, with no interpretation, into the question. Include what you did, what happened, and the output of commands that show permission.

Comment: @richard:  Although that would have been the correct approach, it won't be necessary since the problem is apparently with `/home/user567` not giving `x` access to `user123`.

Comment: @JuliePelletier where did you read that (`/home/user567` not giving `r` access to `user123`)?

Comment: @richard:  Since when do people set up their user home directories to be accessible to everyone else?  That's just a simple deduction, especially since it's the only apparent possibility unless OP did another mistake in their question.

Comment: @Christopher Yes, I know `ls -l` should have shown an ACL indicator. I'm asking anyway because the case is unclear, the posted information is unreliable and double checking worth the effort.

Comment: The problem was that /home suddenly went 700. I think it was set to it by accident.

Comment: Setting `/home` to `700` is not a bad idea in itself since users would normally already be in their home directory so they would have access to their stuff, but they couldn't do anything stupid like changing their home directory permission to give access to everyone else.

Comment: I think this question represents an actual permission problem, unlike a typo or bad command.  For that reason, I think it should not be closed.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal to set permissions so that each user has their own folder that others can not access.  This is why home directories are usually set to `drwxr-x---`.

In order to get to the file `/home/user567/folder/textfile.txt`, the system will need to have directory entry (`x`) access on each of the directories in the path (`/home`, `/home/user567`, and `/home/user567/folder`).

Comment: Permissions on /home are 700. Seems like that is the problem. Is there a way to get into a directory structure like mine? With one folder on 700?

Comment: @marco208: You either give access or you don't.  If you want that specific directory to be accessible to everyone, move it somewhere where they would have access to it.